# \angle symbol in tabular column definition

Tags: tables

I've got a table full of phasors, and I'm trying to write it as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,journal]{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Bus Voltages}
    \label{tab:appdx-busvoltages}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}
        \hline

        \hline
        \textbf{Bus} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{$V$ (p.u.)}} \\
        \hline
            b1 & 1.0 & 0.00 & * \\
            b2 & 0.8983 & -7.12& \\
            b3 & 0.9136 & -5.80 &\\
            b4 & 0.8841 & -9.01 &\\
        \hline

        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    * \textbf{b1} is the `slack bus', and has such has a fixed voltage.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It works, in that it produces the following output:

[image: Output]

But I also get a stack of errors:

```
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@fortmp. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@nextchar. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@preamble. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:111: Only one # is allowed per tab. [...gin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}r@{$^\circ$}l}]
paper1.tex:117: Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. [         b1 & 1.0 &]
paper1.tex:117: Missing $ inserted. [           b1 & 1.0 &]
paper1.tex:117: Missing $ inserted. [           b1 & 1.0 &]
paper1.tex:117: Missing $ inserted. [           b1 & 1.0 &]
paper1.tex:117: Missing $ inserted. [           b1 & 1.0 &]
paper1.tex:118: Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. [         b2 & 0.8983 &]
paper1.tex:118: Missing $ inserted. [           b2 & 0.8983 &]
paper1.tex:118: Missing $ inserted. [           b2 & 0.8983 &]
paper1.tex:118: Missing $ inserted. [           b2 & 0.8983 &]
paper1.tex:118: Missing $ inserted. [           b2 & 0.8983 &]
paper1.tex:119: Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. [         b3 & 0.9136 &]
paper1.tex:119: Missing $ inserted. [           b3 & 0.9136 &]
paper1.tex:119: Missing $ inserted. [           b3 & 0.9136 &]
paper1.tex:119: Missing $ inserted. [           b3 & 0.9136 &]
paper1.tex:119: Missing $ inserted. [           b3 & 0.9136 &]
paper1.tex:120: Missing # inserted in alignment preamble. [         b4 & 0.8841 &]
paper1.tex:120: Missing $ inserted. [           b4 & 0.8841 &]
paper1.tex:120: Missing $ inserted. [           b4 & 0.8841 &]
paper1.tex:120: Missing $ inserted. [           b4 & 0.8841 &]
paper1.tex:120: Missing $ inserted. [           b4 & 0.8841 &]
```

If I remove the `@{$\angle$}` from my column definitions in `\begin{tabular}{...` then the errors go away. Any idea why this is occurring / how I can achieve the same formatting without incurring these errors?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: cheers. I'll get on to that now.

Comment: works for me if I load the `array` package

Comment: Yep, I think @cmhughes has the answer. But also, please ensure that the image provided actually corresponds to the MWE given.

Comment: Yep, that's done it. Thanks @cmhughes! I'll set this up with a MWE for completeness anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if I load the [`array`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/array) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Bus Voltages}
    \label{tab:appdx-busvoltages}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|r@{$\angle$}l@{$^\circ$}l}
        \hline

        \hline
        \textbf{Bus} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{$V$ (p.u.)}} \\
        \hline
            b1 & 1.0 &  & * \\
            b2 & 0.8983 && \\
            b3 & 0.9136 & &\\
            b4 &  & &\\
        \hline

        \hline
        \end{tabular}

    * \textbf{b1} is the `slack bus', and has such has a fixed voltage.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

On another note, have a look at [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)